# jquery error sending message

Tags: jquery

When jquery is running this is not going "success" this is going in "error" section.My php file is on another server.code is like below.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {  

    //if submit button is clicked  
    $('#recaptcha_reload').click(function () { 
   var data ="publick="+document.getElementById("publickeyval").value+"&privatek="+document.getElementById("privatekeyval").value;

 alert(data);
//start the ajax  
      $.ajax({

           //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail  
           url: "http://www.example.com/example_api/example_adcpatchaapi.php",   

           //GET method is used  
           type: "GET",  

           //pass the data           
           data: data,       

           //Do not cache the page  
           cache: false,  

           //success  
           success: function (html) { 
alert(html);

               if (html) {      

document.getElementById('captcha_table').innerHTML=html;    


               }    else{
      alert("####");  // runing this alert box
 }
           },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.status); // showing 0 
        }      
       });  

       //cancel the submit button default behaviours  
       return false;  
   });
```

});

Comment: I am accessing my php file "example_adcpatchaapi.php" remotely.This javascrpt is running on another server.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, same [origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) applies, you cant access pages outside the current domain/server using AJAX

Comment: How will i overcome this problem ? Is it restricted by my hosting plan ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, its restricted by your PHP script being hosted on a different server than your javascript/jquery, if you really want to do it on another server you will have to look into JSONP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSONP](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/107136.aspx) for cross-site callbacks.

Some useful links:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/